# Nullable operator .?

Tags: c#, operators, nullable

I recall I read this somewhere but am not able to find it in Google results now.

Does the newest C# (VS2013) support any such operator?

```
SomeObject.?SomeMember = SomeValue;
```

This is supposed to assign `SomeValue` to `SomeObject.SomeMember` only if `SomeObject` is not null.

N.B: I know we can do this through `HasValue` and other ways. I'm just asking about the new operator.

Comment: I'm basically trying to bind a control to it (ASP.NET WebForms Model Binding). Something like this: `Text='<%# Item.Manufacturer?.Name %>`

Comment: @Jehof: You mean C# 6.0

Comment: Here's the original detailed discussion about this feature on Codeplex: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it has nothing to do with `Nullable` types.It's [null propagation operator](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883) and will work for each type that can be null, not just for `Nullable<T>`, reference types as well.

> Does the newest C# (VS2013) support any such operator?

You could install Roslyn end user preview if you are using VS 2013, or Visual Studio 14 CTP 3

Comment: But does even C# 6 support `SomeObject.?SomeMember = SomeValue`? The null propagation operator is part of of an l-value expression (or whatever the actual name is).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and comprehensive answer. I do like @Dirk's comment/question though.

Comment: @Dirk I think the same thing.that expression can return null, and null = something is not a valid expression. but who knows..

Comment: @Dirk : I don't think it's possible, because it makes as little sense as `cond? var1: var2 = someValue`. It's an interesting enough topic to have its own question though. Be sure to post it.

Answer (score 1):

It is available in the `Roslyn` compiler and it's called [Null-propagation](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home) - it's already implemented. Roslyn compiler will be available in VS 14 by default.

Answer (score 0):

No, Visual Studio 2013 does not support such operator. Not out of the box at least.

If you want to use the [null propagation operator](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883), or any other [C# 6 feature](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home), you will have to install and use the CTP of [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/). Roslyn will be the default compile of Visual studio "14" though (we don't know its definitive name yet).